# What tool or third party to use to download a large number of files with proxy to cloud storage

Tags: cloud-service, data, cloud-storage, download-manager, proxy

So I have urls of a lot of pdf files from various websites. Like 700k of them. I want to download them to my Google Cloud Bucket.

I am getting ip banned from some sites. Thus I was wondering there must be some type of paid platform which will take my list of urls download them in scale and with proxy support to my gcloud storage. That seems like a problem people must have bumped into before me.

Any suggestions?

Note : What I am doing is ethical as I am using my own goverments public archives and the only reason they are ip banning is because they don't have proper servers because they are busy spending their money on more "productive" things.